# How to add XML Google Pay Button in Flutter

Tags: android-layout, flutter, dart, google-pay

My Flutter app uses Google Pay as a payment method. Following [these guidelines](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/brand-guidelines), they provide XML buttons (which I have never dealt with).

How can I add one of these button to a flutter widget using dart?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I literally don't know how to start. Can you use XML in Java or Kotlin like that?

Answer (score 0):

There are different implementations for [laying out content for Android versus Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-lay-out-my-widgets-where-is-my-xml-layout-file).

The `layout/googlepay_button.xml` layout effectively describes the way the button appears, and `drawable/googlepay_button_content.xml` contains [`VectorDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources) file for the Google Pay button. [`flutter_svg`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) should help you render the contents of the image.

To get this to work with Flutter, you would need to reproduce the xml layout as a Flutter widget tree.

Sample layout `black/res/layout/googlepay_button.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48sp"
    android:background="@drawable/googlepay_button_no_shadow_background"
    android:paddingTop="2sp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/googlepay_button_content_description">
    <LinearLayout
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:src="@drawable/googlepay_button_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:src="@drawable/googlepay_button_overlay"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, I see the package. Do you mean convert this xml to an svg? Still not clear on what to do...

Comment: *Draw SVG (and some Android VectorDrawable (XML)) files on a Flutter Widget.* - you may be able to use it as-is. Failing that, you may need to convert `drawable/googlepay_button_content.xml` to SVG first.

Comment: I tried and failed. For now using the google pay mark instead of button to speed up process. 
To anyone else, please let me know if you have had success.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SVG. Try to open all these XML files like SVG, and add it to assets folder in your project.